# On-click adding and removing background color of a table data(td)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, addclass, removeclass

i am using jquery for set background color to the table data and its working fine but i need when user again click the td  the color should be deselect. its my script for add color.

```
java script:
  jQuery('td').click(function () { $(this).addClass('active'); });

my css class:
.active{background-color:red;}
```

when user again click the td the class should remove. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('td').click(function () { $(this).toggleClass('active'); });
```

toggleClass adds if it doesn't exist or removes if it does exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$(this).removeClass('active');
```

although you would need to do a check to see if it is already active, which would make your code look like this:

```
jQuery('td').click(function () { 
  if($(this).hasClass('active') { 
    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
  }
});
```

EDIT:

@Justice is more correct:

```
jQuery('td').click(function () { $(this).toggleClass('active'); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence.  Not sure if the proper etiquette is to upvote you, but thank you.